# All keys gets cleared in REDIS upon restart of server

Tags: redis

I am new to redis.
I created one list and upon restart of redis-server , my list gets cleared off.

How can i make that list non-volatile?

Comment: Check the [doc](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) on how to persist data.

Comment: Yes i am aware of that. But i just want to make use of Redis as cache i.e. whenever i restart the server it should build the existing lists for me as new data set.

Comment: I have enabled option in config file "appendonly yes"

Comment: Did you set an expiration for the list? Also you should make sure that Redis starts with the right config file.

Comment: I am not using any expiration for list.also not using any config file while starting redis-server as it should take the default config file present in instalation directory.

Comment: Are you running on a bare (VM) server or in a container?

Comment: @user1469712 Try `config get appendonly` command to check if your config file takes effect. Also you can specify the config file manually: `./redis path-to-redis.conf`

Comment: I have tried with below command:                                       C:\Program Files\Redis>redis-server .\conf\redis.conf
Usage: ./redis-server [/path/to/redis.conf]
       ./redis-server - (read config from stdin)                                                  but it is not getting started with config file.

Comment: Thanks Guys...it worked for me.